# Classes in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="test">
       <h1>test</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="test">
       <h1>test</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test
{
  background-color: #000;
  .col-md-2;
}
```

where class test try to referencing the class col,but it's not working.

Bootstrap allows reference classes from another classes ?

I used following article to guide me:

[Link](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html)

Comment: you need to use mixins!

Comment: .col-md-2 is not a css rule

Comment: @LuisP.A. there's also no HTML `<h>` element. I'm not even sure what this is supposed to be.

Comment: Read the article again - you'll find that to reference something else within css class, you need to use preprocessors like Sass and Less. But before you start using preprocessors I'd suggest to start learning basics of css, and html

Answer (score 1):

In CSS you cannot nest classes, you need to use SASS or LESS to create these nested class calls:

Example using SASS:

```
.test {
    background-color: #000;
    @include make-md-column(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without SASS, Bootstrap is setup to use class definitions in the HTML to define the grid.  It allows you to better visualize the grid when you're doing structural maintenance.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="test col-md-2">
       <h1>test</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="test col-md-2">
       <h1>test</h1>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.test { background-color: #000; }
```

BTW, out of the box, a black background div with default text would be black-on-black....so you'd never see your text...

Comment: He referenced an article to use LESS or SASS

Comment: man are you sure you can use dots in the css class names? - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner

Comment: No, you can't...my bad, not paying attn to copy-paste

Comment: @bpeterson76 - no probs, thumbs up for straightening mysterious <h> element :)